# Koeppen-Geiger Climatic Zones as netcdf file

Tags: programming

Is there a way to obtain a netcdf file of the Koeppen-Geiger Climatic Zones?

Comment: Does it have to be NetCDF, or could some other open format work, that you could easily convert to NetCDF yourself?

Comment: thanks. the final file needs to be netcdf. how I get there is not of importance..

Answer (score 0):

The Köppen-Geiger climate classification at a high 1‑km resolution for historical and future climate conditions (1901–2099) presented in [Beck et al. (2018)](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata2018214) can be downloaded in GTIFF format from the following URL: https://www.gloh2o.org/koppen/

Choosing your favourite framework, you can now easily convert this into netCDF format. Using e.g. the `{terra}` package (wrapping GDAL) in R, it's as easy as that:

```
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71

# read as SpatRaster object
r <- rast("koppen_geiger_0p00833333.tif")
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : koppen_geiger_0p00833333.tif 
#> color table : 1 
#> name        : koppen_geiger_0p00833333

# dump to disk in netCDF format
writeRaster(r, "koppen_geiger_0p00833333.nc", wopt = list(datatype="INT1U"))
```

Or you can use GDAL directly if you like:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF koppen_geiger_0p00833333.tif koppen_geiger_0p00833333.nc
```